# Difference between Kotlin Coroutine ,Android Async Task and Async await

Tags: android, android-asynctask, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I went through the Kotlin Coroutine, I understood how it works but I have a confusion between Kotlin coroutine & Android Async.execute() & Async await. The Kotlin coroutine runs in the background and does not block on the UI thread but the same thing happens when we start android AsyncTask(with the methods `doInBackground` `onPostExecute` and `onProgressUpdate` overridden), it also does the computation in a background thread and publishes the result on the UI thread.

Async-await returns a Deffered object means the result will obviously going to be returned in future.

Can Anyone Explain what's the difference between these.

Comment: Essentially they do the same thing but only differs in the details and API set up. All of them executes the tasks asynchronously and provides ways for you to get results in the future, await just makes the same thread wait for that future result, essentially forcing the task to be synchronous.

Comment: Main Difference i see `AsyncTask` by default runs in `SingleThreadPoolExecuter` so you can not run multiple `AsyncTask` in parallel  by default . Apart from this `AsyncTask` usually left the memory leak if not handled properly .. I a nut shell Kotlin Coroutine are elegant way for asynchronous call without any callback Inteface quite similar to `RXjava`..

Comment: @jackz314 if i am using async await like this myAPIService.getWeather(location).await() and then myAPIService.getDetails(id).await() , you means to say first api get the result of getWeather  and then getDetails ??

Comment: Yeah if you call `await()` then the thread will wait for the task to complete to execute the next line, which is the same behavior as normal synchronous code.

Comment: They all solve the same problem. The background processing. The idea is which one is the best. I personally use coroutines. Google has already deprecated `AsyncTask`.

They just have different implementations

Comment: https://medium.com/@iam_manoj/multitasking-with-process-threads-coroutines-5298a57ee75 -- it tells u difference between thread and coroutine in quite simple way

Answer (score 5):

Let's try to break this down:

> The Kotlin coroutine runs in the background

A coroutine **CAN** run in the background

> does not block on the UI thread

Let's talk about what a coroutine is:

A coroutine can be thought of as the code that gets passed to one of the coroutine builder functions i.e. `launch {}`

By definition when a coroutine is launched, suspend functions within it do not block the corresponding `Thread` when they are reached; they "pause" the coroutine.

When the suspension point is reached, it is as if you were telling the code to "call you back later" when the result is available; a suspension point can be though of as a callback.

Let's look at an example:

```kotlin
fun main() {
 val job = MainScope().launch {
  doSomeWork()
}

suspend fun doSomeWork() {/*expensive work goes here*/}
}
```

When `doSomeWork()` is reached the code will suspend the coroutine, i.e. the suspend modifier is indicating to the coroutine framework that it can go do some other coroutine related work and then come back to this point when `doSomeWork()` is done.

Since this coroutine is launched using `MainScope()` it will be launched in the main `Thread`. That is why I said that coroutines **CAN** run in a background `Thread` but not always do so. In this case it does not, but it still does not block the UI `Thread`.

In the other hand, `AsyncTask` was (it is deprecated as of API 30) a mechanism that performed a tasks in a background `Thread` and posted the result back to the UI `Thread`

For the difference between `CoroutineScope.async{}` and `CoroutineScope.launch{}` we can look at the return values for each. As I showed in the example. `launch{}` returns a `Job` which is a representation of the lifecycle of the coroutine itself. Using the `Job` you can `cancel()` or `join()` the coroutine; you have control over its lifecycle. As you mention, `async{}` returns a `Deffered<T>` which is a representation of a future value. When `await()` is called on the `Deffered<T>` the coroutine is suspended until the result is ready to be consumed.